# Assigning the value of a javascript variable within function arguments?

Tags: javascript

I'm sending an `XMLHttpRequest`.

In the `open` function I want to set some parameters for the request.

```
req.open('GET', /some/path?someparam=*somevariable*, true)
```

I want to get `someparam` to equal the value of a variable, like `var somevariable`. In fact the variable name might even have the same name as `someparam`.

How do I  get the variable to resolve in this instance?

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation and [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to make sure you are producing a valid URI:

```
'/some/path?someparam=' + encodeURIComponent(somevariable)
```

In an ES6 environment you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
`/some/path?someparam=${encodeURIComponent(somevariable)}`
```